# How to use Visual Studio's Wix Toolset Extension to install a Windows Form application?

Tags: visual-studio, wix3

Following [this basic tutorial](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html) I have created a Windows Form App (.NET Core) project in C# called MyApplication, and to the same solution, I added a Setup Project for WiX v3 called MySetup, both named as prescribed by the aforementioned tutorial. I am using Visual Studio 2019. I added the Windows Form App to the References node in the Solution Explorer, and as described by the linked tutorial, I added `<File Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetPath)" />` as shown below, to `Product.wxs`.

```
    <Fragment>
      <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="ProductComponent">
          <File Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetPath)" />
        </Component>
      </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
```

When I build the Wix v3 project, I get an `msi` file. When I run this, it produces a `dll` file from my form application in the intended directory (`Program Files (x86)\MySetup` as per the instructions). This is nice, but I want an `exe` file so I can run the application from the installation directory.

Reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2019), I guessed that the macro `$(var.MyApplication.TargetPath)` was the issue, but I was not able to find a way to change this. So, I tried to see what happened when I substituted this segment for the full path of the `exe` file (`\MyApplication\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\MyApplication.exe`). Rebuilding and rerunning the `msi` file again, this successfully put the `exe` file in the desired location. However, when opening this exe, the Windows Form doesn't even show up, whereas in `bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\` it still opens a blank window as expected. My approach doesn't seem to be working at all, so I think I might be misunderstanding something fundamental about how to get this stuff working.

My goal is to just get the `msi` to produce a working version of the blank Windows Forms application in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySetup` as per the linked tutorial, instead of a faceless `dll`. Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To install a working application, you'll need to include all the files written by a publish command.

[This tutorial](https://nblumhardt.com/2017/04/netcore-msi/) was written for net core 1.1, but looks like it should work.